# Install Linux Mint On Macbook (*Not dual or multi-boot*)

Tags: boot, partitioning, linux-mint, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro 15-inch, Early 2011 running OS X (10.7.5).  I no longer want OS X installed (hated it from day 1 back when the system was new) and would like to replace it with Linux Mint 17.  I *do not want to dual or multi-boot* which I see lots of instructions to set up.  I need to understand what is necessary to have only Mint installed (partition the whole drive for Mint - no OS X).  I have a Mint .iso burned to a USB flash drive.

Can I simply boot the laptop off the flash drive and once in the Mint desktop use the install icon on the desktop, handling my desired partitioning during the install??  Looks like maybe the boot order has to be addressed (https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1643)?

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way is to treat the computer as a BIOS-mode PC: Wipe the partition table, create a new ***[Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)*** partition table, and install Linux ***in BIOS mode.*** These days an EFI-mode install may also work, but is more likely to cause problems in a single-boot scenario.